# Create an outlook add-in global level

Tags: outlook-addin

I am attempting to venture down the Outlook Add-In road.

Basically - i need to add a few grouped buttons in the ribbon bar.  Each button will perform a web service call with the credentials (email address) of the user.

Question : Is there a way to create a add-in that is at the Outlook level (ribbon level), not in the email (ribbon) level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to develop a VSTO based add-in for Outlook where you can create a custom ribbon UI. See [Walkthrough: Create your first VSTO Add-in for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2019) to get started quickly.

There are two ways for creating a custom UI in VSTO add-ins:

1. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using the Ribbon Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-the-ribbon-designer?view=vs-2019)
2. [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2019)

Web Add-ins work in the context of an item and also allows creating ribbon buttons, but very limited if we compare to VSTO add-ins, see [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) to get started quickly.